# Mongoose User.findOne neither return error nor success

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-facebook

In passport-facebook Strategy, when I query using Mongoose User.findOne() it doesn't return error or success object. Nodejs when come to this block, escape this block User.findOne(){...} without giving any error and success i.e.silently escape.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.get('facebook.clientID'),
        clientSecret: config.get('facebook.clientSecret'),
        callbackURL: config.get('facebook.callbackURL'),
        passReqToCallback: true,
        profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // check if the user is already logged in
        let fbInfo = profile._json;
        // console.log(fbInfo);

        if (!req.user) {
            User.findOne({ 'email': fbInfo.email }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (user) {
```

Comment: This is not escaping, your email is not matching in any doc and it returns null. Can you add console.log(err,user) above all if and see the result?

Comment: User.findOne({ 'email': fbInfo.email }, function(err, user) { console.log(err,user);
this console.log doesn't  execute

Comment: can you check `req.user` value? I think your condition is not satisfied do it as `req.user` not `!req.user`

Comment: @TareqAhamed check my answer and see if it solves your problem. If it solves your problem please mark it as correct and upvote it. If you have any problems, comment under my answer.

Comment: sorry Codearts, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't make it inside the if statement. 
Change `if (!req.user)` to `if (req.user)` and it should work.

--

However here is some sample code using Passport Facebook authentication strategy:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: oauth.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: oauth.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: oauth.facebook.callbackURL,
    // passReqToCallback: true,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name']
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        User.findOne({
          $or: [
            { 'facebook.id': profile.id },
            { 'email': profile.emails[0].value }
          ]
        }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err)
          }

          if (user) {
            if (user.facebook.id == undefined) {
              user.facebook.id = profile.id
              user.facebook.token = accessToken
              user.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value
              user.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName
              user.save()
            }

            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            let newUser = new User()
            ...

            newUser.save(err => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                throw err
              }

              return done(null, newUser)
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  ))
```